# Search for data in an array in a document in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection organization with field

```
users: [  
  {  
     "user_id":"1",
     "role":"1"
  },
  {  
     "user_id":"2",
     "role":"2"
  }]
```

and another collection users with fields

```
{
  {"user_id":1},
  {"user_id":2},
  {"user_id":3},
  {"user_id":4}
}
```

I need to display all users with user id present in the users array in the organizations collection. What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Try [`lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to display the user_id of the users in the organization you have to unwind users field and do the project on user_id field like below.

```
collection.aggregate([{"$unwind","$users"},{"$project":{"user_id":"$users.user_id"}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.myDbCollection.find({}, {"user_id": 1});
```

can use this statement to find data from your collection.